# Save all data of Network Panel of Firefox DevTools

Tags: networking, firefox

I would like to know how do I save all data from the Network Panel, including CallStack, of Firefox DevTools?

Comment: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/982088 does this help?

Comment: What have you tried so far? It seems to me this is a pretty simple process or something a pretty simple web search would answer. Have you done some research yet? What have your learned, and where are you having trouble?

Comment: The link developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Debugging/HTTP_logging solved my problem. Thanks Timmy Browne.